# What type of rack is used to host Netgear and cisco routers and switches?

Tags: router, switch, rackspace

I'm a Masters student doing a project on how to design and deploy networks in an industry environment.

Theoretically, I have 6 Netgear ProSafe fs750 switches and a Cisco 3750 24T-S switch and want to put them in a rack. Cost is a constraint because the lower the budget, the better grade I get(
I'm lying, that's not got to do with anything! :)
)

I have no idea what companies are out there for router rack space and at what prices. I just want to know what types of racking spaces are used in the industry and what is most often used in case I have to stack something that is 6 RUs... (I found a 12 RU rack online for $197, just want to know if that's the right choice)

Comment: Shopping or buying recommendation are not a good fit for this site.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: If you're getting a 19 inch rack, and if it matters to your hardware, get one with really nice ventillation and a closed front, and perhaps air filters. This reduces dust (Now for switches, I'm not sure this matters much, but if you've got servers in there too, it's recommended).

Comment: @u4ik I'm generally opposed to closed-face racks for cooling reasons - you can't really get decent density because your gear can't draw in enough cold air.  Less of an issue for networking gear, but heat is a big thing when you have 40 dual-socket quad-core boxes filling up a rack :)

Comment: Well with that much horsepower, it's not likely you'll fit 40 servers in with some networking switches, and usually what I do is spread the servers apart to offer some more air in between. But some of the closed cases have powerful fans in them.

Comment: I'd like to point out to all those that closed my question that this is not a buying recommendation question. I am a Masters student at CU Boulder and am not really buying these devices. I am doing this for a project and thus need some guidance as to what is actually used in the industry. Maybe my question should have been - What type of racks are used in the industry for routers and switches?

Comment: @Nitin See the answer below - 19 inch racks are the standard.  Probably the most commonly used size is 42U.

Comment: It depends what room you're installing into: Is this a single rack in a comms room or a dedicated air-conditioned room? If you're designing the physical space too, you want some physical barrier around the rack to limit airflow between front and rear: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_center_environmental_control#Hot.2FCold_Aisle_Containment If it's just a box in a room, under-populate the rack to limit heat and focus on sound barriers (foam etc). Remember watts electricity in = watts heat out.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend an [industry-standard 19 inch rack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19-inch_rack).  Preferably square-hole (you can buy [cage nuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cage_nut) if necessary).
(I'm trying not to be facetious, but that's really the only answer, and likely the only kind of rack you will find at any datacenter/hosting company)

Comment: Could also use a telco style rack with those little switches...

Comment: True - I kinda count two-post telco racks in the broader family of 19-inch racks, but they're really a second cousin once removed: They'd never hold a 65xx series switch or a good 6U server :)